# Can I force to disable xss auditor on chrome by js or html?

Tags: html, google-chrome, jsp, xss

My webpage.jsp is unable to view because of chrome not setting `--disable-xss-auditor`.
It is known that it can be solved by opening `chrome.exe --disable-xss-auditor`.
But are there any ways(js code or html code) that can achieve the same thing without the stated method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/xss-auditor):

> Sites may control the XSS Auditor's behavior using the
>   `X-XSS-Protection` response header, either disabling the feature or
>   changing its mode.
>
> This Response header disables the Auditor:
>
> ```
> X-XSS-Protection: 0
> ```

Comment: Anybody planning to do this: your website is likely vulnerable to cross-site scripting, not because you disable XSS Auditor, but because you are doing something by design that looks very much like XSS, so a real XSS would probably also work.

Comment: It is something you need to be extremely careful about.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your response.For jsp server,is it adding something like `response.setIntHeader("x-xss-Protection",0)` on top?

Comment: @KenyKeny — That looks plausible. I know nothing about JSP APIs though.